# angularjs not updating the auto binding

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to write an anuglarjs UI, I can't get it to auto update the binding of data.message from a text box.
Is something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

<body>
<center>

<div ng-app="">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
<h1>{{data.message + "world"}} </h1>
</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='init.js'></script>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.19.js" ng:autobind></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

It doesnt auto update it, i just get "0world" as a return, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a pretty old version of AngularJS. I took your code, changed the version to 1.0.6, and it just works:

http://jsbin.com/ayahip/2/edit